# Powershell command as variable, with or without leading $ outside brackets?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, variables, syntax

```
Powershell version:

Name                           Value                                                                                    
----                           -----                                                                                    
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.1007                                                                           
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                  
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                  
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.1007                                                                          
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                          
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                      
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                      
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

If I try

```
foreach ($file in $(ls C:\)) { echo 'foo' }
```

in the powershell console, it works.

If i put it inside a job in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I get a syntax error.
The working syntax is without the $

```
foreach ($file in (ls C:\)) { echo 'foo' }
```

Why is that? What's the correct syntax? The console accepts both

Comment: because the leading `$` in `$(ls c:\)` is not needed in any way at all. it will work in the standard PoSh host ... but may not in others. adding needless complexity to your code is always a bad idea ... and you just found one more reason why. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey What's the "grin" all about?

Comment: it's about "i am old and can't see `:)` very well" ... so i use spelled-out emoticons. and i use emoticons because the side-band communication [vocal tone, facial expression, body language, etc.] in text is non-existent .. so i add some indicator of what my side-band communication _would_ be. every time you see me show such, it reflects my intent AND usually matches my actual facial expression. [*grin*]

Comment: Essentially, you always use the grouping operator, unless you need to get the result from within a double-quoted string. In that case, you will use the subexpression. See Grouping operator and Subexpression operator on the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1).